# No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "IMGSource", or mismatching type between value and property

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have added a image property as a Bindable Property, in that property the image will get bind by the backend where in the list we are getting image in URI form.(Below is the link of image)
"http://103.117.66.70:5002/AllMedia/Categories/1ij0oc2022_12_29_img.png"

My Bindable Property code is Below:-

This Image is defined in one custom ContentView where i am binding this custom Content View in one page.

```
    <Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference This}, Path=IMGSource}" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
    
    public static readonly BindableProperty IMGSourceBindablePropertyProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IMGSource), typeof(Uri), typeof(Uri));
            public Uri IMGSource
            {
                get { return (Uri)GetValue(IMGSourceBindablePropertyProperty); }
                set { SetValue(IMGSourceBindablePropertyProperty, value); }
            }

MainPage.xmal


<control:Accordion FrameEye="True" GridTitle="{Binding title}" IMGSource="{Binding RowImg}" GridTitleFontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
```

Comment: did you assign "This" name to your ContentView ?

Comment: @puko yes, even i able to show image but in binding the image the error message "No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "IMGSource", or mismatching type between value and property" is appearing

Comment: RowImg is type of Uri ?

Comment: @puko is of string but i have tried with both URI and string

Comment: the second type in your definition is wrong. I think it is declaringType, in your case typeof(Accordion) - i assume that Accordion is your customview

Comment: @puko yes i have changed it but it didn't work.............

public static readonly BindableProperty IMGSourceBindablePropertyProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IMGSource), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(Accordion));
        public ImageSource IMGSource
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(IMGSourceBindablePropertyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IMGSourceBindablePropertyProperty, value); }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the name of your `IMGSourceBindablePropertyProperty` and declaring type.

The naming convention for bindable properties is that the bindable property identifier must match the property name specified in the Create method, with "Property" appended to it. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties)

It should look like

```
public static readonly BindableProperty IMGSourceProperty = 
                BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IMGSource), typeof(string), typeof(Accordion));

public string IMGSource
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(IMGSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IMGSourceProperty, value); }
}
```